# Is this an invertible linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb R} T:\R^2\rightarrow \R^3$

$T(x)=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0 &0\end{bmatrix}x, \forall x\in \R^2$

I know that a linear map is invertible if and only if the map is bijective. By looking at the matrix which is injective the map is not invertible. But I thought could it be an invertible map if the codomain $\R^3$ is changed to the subspace in $\R^3$, i.e.,$\text{span}\{[1\; 0\; 0]^{\top}, [0\; 1\; 0]^{\top}\}$, because in this way the map becomes both injective and surjective. If it is a linear invertible map, then what is the matrix representation of this linear map?

Comment: There cannot be a bijective linear map between $\mathbb R^{2}$ and $\mathbb R^{3}$ because they have different dimensions. The question says $T:R^2\rightarrow R^3$, and you cannot change the codomain.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron If it becomes invertible by restricting range then why the matrix representation is still non-invertible?

Comment: @ChuanHuang Oops sorry my bad. The matrix representation with respect to the basis I gave is just $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and not what I wrote. I blindly copied the code from your question.

Comment: To see this, let $(a,b,0)$ be any vector in $span\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$. Then it can be written as $(a,b,0)=a\cdot (1,0,0)+b(0,1,0)$ . So as $T(1,0)=1\cdot (1,0,0)+0(0,1,0)$ and $T(0,1)=0\cdot (1,0,0)+1\cdot (0,1,0)$ you have that the matrix is given by $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: When you learn about rank-nullity theorem, you can easily arrive at a contradiction :)

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks! It is exactly what I have been thinking of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. The considered map, namely $T : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^3, (x,y) \mapsto (x,y,0)$ is nothing else than the canonical injection from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}^3$. As indicated by its name, it is indeed injective, since its kernel is trivial, but it is not surjective (and thus non-invertible), because $\dim \mathrm{im\;} T = 2 < \dim \Bbb{R}^3 = 3$, or $T(\Bbb{R}^2) = \Bbb{R}^2 \otimes \{0\} \subsetneq \Bbb{R}^3$ in other words. More concretely, you can notice that $e_3 = (0,0,1) \in \Bbb{R}^3$ has no preimage.

Comment: Given what the poster has asked, I think it’s important to note that You absolutely can restrict the codomain to be the image of the linear map, in which case it would be an isomorphism onto its image, which seems to be what OP is getting at without the proper terminology to express it.